# Too much time before Main Activity is running and screen is updated

Tags: android, android-emulator, main-activity

My App needs too much time before Main Activity is running and screen is updated

When I test my App in some old cell phones or on Android Emulator, before the main App is showed, the app show it another "screen". That screen is no well configurate from design point of view.

I don't want to show that screen, there is some configuratión to change?
What is that "screen"? Is system screen?
Or there is some problem with my code and performance?

Can someone help me?

Thanks and sorry for my poor english

Comment: can you describe the screen you're getting before your main view comes up?

Comment: It is my background image but with other size and with other title.

Comment: Are you doing something that takes a lot of time in your onCreate, onStart, or onResume?

Comment: if possible post u r code here

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start by creating an activity with a progress bar, or a Splash screen activity, just to appear at first, and then have that activity launch the new activity that takes longer to load. Then, at the end of that second activity's on create, you could notify the splash screen or progress bar activity through an Intent, and have the splash screen finish, letting the second activity be brought to foreground after it has already been loaded.